# Child access parent variable / Define variable once, use it in entire application

Tags: c++, qt

Consider the following code:

`class.h`

```
public:
    QString dataDirectory;
```

`class.cpp`

```
dataDirectory = QApplication::applicationDirPath();
dataDirectory.append("/../data");
```

`child.h`

```
class Child : public QDialog
```

`child.cpp`

```
QString dataFile = parent()->dataDirectory; // Fails
dataFile.append("myfile.txt");
```

Of course I tried to cast it with an qobject_cast, like so:

```
 ParentClass *myParent = qobject_cast<class *>(parent());
 QString dataFile = myParent->dataDirectory; // Fails (I even get a segfault);
```

No success. I also tried to change the constructor of the child, but I get a few dozen error messages of what is not defined. Although I used forward declaration and avoided to include the header files.

All I want is to have one place where I define the directory path and access it in my whole application. In another language I know better that would be really, really simple, but in C++ I can't get it to work :/

The problem is a really basic one and I'm kinda embarrassed not to find a solution, but my Parent and Child are both QWidgets and I can't find any way to access the parents variable in the child.

Comment: Please add example code what you did and how it failed to your question. "*Of course I tried to cast it with an qobject_cast. No success.*" is not an adequate problem description.

Comment: @dom0 done that. Sorry, I thought it so trivial ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `private` data member and a `public` and `static` getter function, returning `const QString &` made from the data member.

Comment: How can I create a static getter for an object related String? Could you please add an example code?

Answer (score 0):

"My" solution (thanks to dom0)

```
QString parent::dir()
{
    return QGuiApplication::applicationDirPath().append("/../data/");
}
```